# How can I dress up a boring drop ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, basement-refinishing

I don't like the look of the standard drop ceiling tiles in my finished basement.  I'd like to replace them with something like the one picture below.  However, the cost of these is prohibitive given the size of my basement due to its size.

Alternatively, are there any ideas for updating the ceiling to make it look less boring and give it (at least the appearance) of more height?

[image: ceiling tile]

Comment: Shopping requests are off topic for Home Improvement. If nothing else they become outdated very quickly. I've edited the question to make it more general.

Comment: -1 because this looks like decorating and shopping advice which don't work well here. There isn't a correct answer, just lots of opinions, and answers will be very location dependent and quickly outdated.

Comment: Seems like they are asking - what are the alternatives to drop ceiling tiles?

Comment: He's asking for ideas to improve an appearance of something not where to buy xyz.  You're free to propose something entirely different that he could try.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen basement ceilings done with scrap hardwood flooring that looked really good.  Not sure if you have to have the drop ceiling...

Answer (score 0):

Some restaurants have removed drop ceilings all together. They often paint the ceilings black including all pipework that once was hidden. It gives an industrial look and a sense of height.

I'm not sure if this might be an option for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

**'floating' floating ceiling (for lack of a better term).**

This is a technique I used for my basement remodel. I built a trimmed out frame that the ceiling tiles then fit into. I left about 2' around this frame exposed joists. I did this for 3 reasons 1) cost: leaving out the perimeter space saved money on tiles I didn't need to purchase. 2) functionality: it's a basement. It will always be a basement. Having access to all the mechanicals up there is nice. 3) aesthetics: I felt it offered a bit of a unique look, somewhat industrial/loft-esque.

**paint**

Take down you current tiles and paint them. Color can make a big difference.